# Link by internal path in *.links.menu.yml not visible in admin menu

Tags: 8, users, navigation

Based on the official [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-menu-link) to create menu links I've tried to use an internal link on the administration menu. But the internal link is only visible for users with administrator rights.

In my `my_module.links.menu.yml` I use the following links for testing:

```
my_module.test_link:
  title: 'TEST LINK internal'
  url: internal:/node/add
  description: 'TEST internal'
  parent: system.admin_content
  weight: 99

my_module.test_link_2:
  title: 'TEST LINK external'
  url: https://www.stackoverflow.com
  description: 'TEST external'
  parent: system.admin_content
  weight: 100
```

Both links are visible for administrators, but an user with editor role does only see the external link.

I activate every permission for the editor role, the link remains invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be necessary to use a **route_name** for this. Then you can control permissions and the internal link is visible for the editor role too:

1 – Change **`my_module.links.menu.yml`** to use a **route_name** instead of the url:

```
my_module.test_link:
  title: 'TEST LINK internal'
  route_name: my_module.test_route
  description: 'TEST internal'
  parent: system.admin_content
  weight: 99
```

2 – Add the route with  permission to my routing file **`my_module.routing.yml`**:

```
my_module.test_route:
  path: '/node/add'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```