# How to add internal path in *.links.menu.yml

Tags: routes, 9

I am trying to add an internal link to admin toolbar but I am not able to achieve it.

According to [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/step-by-step-tutorial-hello-world/add-a-menu-link#s-additional-tips) we add an internal link in `*.links.menu.yml` in the below manner but the link is not being appeared in the toolbar.

```
hello_world.admin2:
  title: 'Hello module settings'
  description: 'example of how to make an admin settings page link'
  parent: system.admin_config_development
  url: internal:/node/123
```

I tried the following variants as well but none works. `url: 'internal:/node/123'` or `uri: internal:/node/123` or `uri: 'internal:/node/123'` .

But the following works `url: http://localhost/node/123` .

Can anyone suggest me a way to create a menu link in `*.links.menu.yml` file.

**Use case** : I want to provide easily accessible link to user to access one particular page. It is not a route. I am aware of other way to create menu link by using `MenuLinkContent::create` method. But trying to figure out why above method is not working.

Comment: Related https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253789

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know thy this doesn't work (it is a valid input for `Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri`), but `/node/123` actually has a route:

```
hello_world.admin2:
  route_name: entity.node.canonical
  route_parameters:
    node: 123
```

Even though they are valid inputs, it is generally a good idea to avoid `internal:` URLs if you can use something better. "Something better" is either a route name (in the context of `links.yml` files) or an entity scheme `entity:node/123` (in the context of storing links in the DB). AFAIK `internal:` was meant for local unrouted URLs like e.g. `internal:/robots.txt`

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. It works. Bit i am still wondering why the method in question is not working. I will wait couple of days to check if anyone can provide any additional information on why it is not working. Or else I will mark your answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

[@miststudent2011](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/71454/miststudent2011) I think the idea you're missing is that a menu link offers *either* a route *or* a url.

From the [Drupal 10.1 Menu API intro page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/group/menu/):

> links point to routes or URLs.

From the [Drupal 10.1 documentation for function hook_menu_links_discovered_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_links_discovered_alter):

> **route_name**: (optional) The route name to be used to build the path. Either the route_name or url element must be provided.
>
> **route_parameters**: (optional) The route parameters to build the path.
>
> **url**: (optional) If you have an external link use this element instead of providing route_name.

Put simply, use route_name for internal links.  Use url for external links.
Not both!